# asp.net cache doens't work well in windows azure

Tags: asp.net

I am building news website. I am using `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache` to cache retrieved news from sql server database. cached data depends on *mytable*

**Code**

```
public static List<NewsItem> RetriveTop5VideosLastMonth()
    {


        // if null then fetch from the database
        if (System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache["topvideos"] == null)
        {
            using (SqlConnection dbConnection = getConnection())
            {

                // Create the cache dependency
                SqlCacheDependency dep = new SqlCacheDependency("mytable", "news");

                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("RetriveTop5VideosLastMonth", dbConnection);
                ad.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ad.Fill(ds);

                List<NewsItem> lst = new List<NewsItem>();
                foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {

                    lst.Add(new NewsItem() { id = item["id"].ToInt(), link = item["link"].ToString(), title = item["title"].ToString(), category = item["category"].ToString(), description = item["description"].ToString(), entry_date = Convert.ToDateTime(item["entry_date"].ToString()), image = checkEmptyImage(item["image"].ToString()), source = item["source"].ToString(), views = item["views"].ToInt() });
                }


                // put in the cache object
                System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("topvideos", lst, dep);
            }
        }


        return System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache["topvideos"] as List<NewsItem>;


    }
```

so it should remove cached data when mytable's data change. In windows azure i change mytable data but cached data still exist ! where's my mistake ?

Comment: HttpRuntime caching with SqlDependency works fine in Azure. You need to start the listener with SqlDependency.Start method before creating SqlCacheDependency. For more details, look at example http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/c-sqldependency-monitoring

Comment: @rba thanks, it solved the problem, please add this as answer to select it as correct answer for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpRuntime caching with SqlDependency works fine in Azure. You need to start the listener with SqlDependency.Start method before creating SqlCacheDependency. For more details, look at example dotnet.dzone.com/articles/c-sqldependency-monitoring

SqlDependency.Start method starts a listener to receive dependency change notifications from the SQL Server specified by the connection string. If there were some changes in underlying data, SQL Server detects them and posts a notification to the client through the underlying SqlConnection that was created by SqlDependency.Start method.

Please note that the SqlDependency.Stop method must be called for each SqlDependency.Start call to release the listener.